# How to change an object's value across all methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a project in which their is entity or class known as research study , which have a field `title` and `mobile title`. Now I am using a gem to detect the visitor's device (desktop, mobile, etc). Now, what I want is for desktops it should always return 'title' and for all other devices, it should return 'mobile title'.

How can I achieve this so that I don't need to change all my methods in my application wherever I'm returning research study? Is there any solution so that if I change this at single place and it should reflect in all methods?

Edited : Since this have lot of downvotes, I would like to clear up what I need. Here is my class:

```
        class ResearchStudy < ActiveRecord::Base
         attr_accessible \
          :title,
          :mobile_title
           ....
         end
```

And here is my controller where the method is to get all studies and a filter to get the device type like this:

```
class Api::ResearchStudiesController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :check_agent

    def check_agent
        @ua = AgentOrange::UserAgent.new(request.user_agent)
    end


 def get_all_studies
    .....
  answer_status_for_user() // before returning studies i modify the title according to device type
     render json: { studies: @studies.to_json(:include => [:research_paper]) }
 end

def answer_status_for_user
if @ua.is_mobile?
            @studies.each do |study|
                study.title = study.mobile_title
            end
        end
end
```

Now the issue is that in `get_all_studies` I have various methods in application, since it is pretty big application, so sometimes the study does not go in response (`@studies`) like above. What I want is something like whenever we load the studies I want to apply a some changes (may be in constructor or something) which return the `mobile_title` instead of `title`, something like in `ResearchStudy` class itself or any other solution, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: i have edited the question to provide a clear view , please have a look and guide

Answer (score 1):

You can override the attribute reader for this case in your model.

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title
    if device_is_mobile?
      "Title for Mobile"
    else
      "Default title"
    end
  end
end

your_object = YourModel.last
your_object.title # it will give you title depending upon which device being used.
```

Since you are modifying the default reader for you model, it will be accessible all across your web application as well as in Rails console.